# How to download and open PDF files?

Tags: pdf

I am a university student that has most of the lectures online as pdf files. How can I get them on my Android phone and read them through Adobe Reader? This is the first time that I have used Android. The version that I have is 2.2 "Froyo".

Answer (score 3):

1. Download and install [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en) on your phone.  You can find it by the link or by opening up Google Play / Market on your phone and searching for "Adobe Reader".  There are lots of other pdf readers out there too, btw.
2. Either download the PDFs from whatever website they are on using your browser (the built in browser is fine), or download them on your computer, [connect your Android phone by USB cable & mount the SD card](http://support.google.com/ics/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168464), copy the PDF files to the SD card, disconnect your phone from the computer, and finally use the file manager (usually called "Files" in the app drawer) to navigate to the PDF file you want to read.  Tap it's icon once and it should open in your PDF reader.

Answer (score 2):

Store PDFs in your Dropbox account and download them on Android using Dropbox app.

When it comes to download from web, I never faced any problem with that, but if your default downloader suck at downloading PDFs, download them using Opera Mobile web browser. Opera Mobile has in-built downloader. It doesn't hand over downloading to system-wide download handler. If you don't like Opera Mobile like me, there are many dedicated download managers in Play Store... Just, search.

Comment: Just for your information: We don't normally thank each other here :-) Instead, you should accept the answer that you think answered your question best by clicking the green checkmark left to it. You can also useful answers and questions as soon as you have the necessary reputation.